# Why I get error - missing ) after argument list when button generated dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create table with buttons.

Here is the javascript code:

```
function layersListTable(layers) {
    var content ='<table data-role="table" id="layersListEditable" ><thead><tr></tr></thead>';
    $.each($(layers), function () {
        content += '<tr>';
        content += '<td><button data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="edit" onclick="getProperties(' + this.Id +','+ this.Title + ')" data-theme="b" type="button" >Edit</button></td>';
        content += '</tr>';
    });
    content += '</table>';

    return content;
}
```

The table is created by javascript and attached to DOM.

But when I click on the button in the created table, I get this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

When I remove one parameter(this.Title) from button in table:

```
function layersListTable(layers) {
    var content ='<table data-role="table" id="layersListEditable" ><thead><tr></tr></thead>';
    $.each($(layers), function () {
        content += '<tr>';
        content += '<td><button data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="edit" onclick="getProperties(' + this.Id +')" data-theme="b" type="button" >Edit</button></td>';
        content += '</tr>';
    });
    content += '</table>';

    return content;
}
```

it's work`enter code here` perfect.

Any idea why I get error above and how to fix it?

Comment: <fieldset> Start tag is missing in code

Comment: Can the title or ID contains quote or apostrophe ?

Comment: Basically, you have a layer with Title that have a space in between so ) is not detected a the closing ). See Rory's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is due to how you append the arguments in the `onclick` attribute. Presumably they are strings, and hence need to be wrapped in quotes. To do this you will need to escape a single quote around them, like this:

```
content += '<td><button data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="edit" onclick="getProperties(\'' + this.Id +'\',\''+ this.Title + '\')" data-theme="b" type="button" >Edit</button></td>';
```

However, a much better solution would be to remove the outdated `on*` event attribute and avoid this problem entirely by using an unobtrusive event handler. As you've already included jQuery, here's how you can do that:

```
function layersListTable(layers) {
    var content ='<table data-role="table" id="layersListEditable" ><thead><tr></tr></thead>';
    $.each($(layers), function () {
        content += '<tr>';
        content += '<td><button class="edit" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="edit" data-id="' + this.Id + '" data-title="' + this.Title + '" data-theme="b" type="button">Edit</button></td>';
        content += '</tr>';
    });
    content += '</table>';
    content += '</fieldset>'

    return content;
}

$('#layersListEditable').on('click', 'button.edit', function() {
  var $btn = $(this);
  var id = $btn.data('id');
  var title = $btn.data('title');
  getProperties(id, title);
});
```

Finally, note that your code is missing the `<fieldset>` opening tag and a `<tbody>` wrapping the appended `tr` elements - although I presume this is just an error in transposing the question from you production code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem, replace this line it will definitely fix your problem:

```
content += '<td><button data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-icon="edit" onclick="getProperties(\'' + this.Id +'\',\''+ this.Title + '\')" data-theme="b" type="button" >Edit</button></td>';
```

Comment: Note you've missed the quotes in the middle of the argument list

Comment: Yes I have just noted that and edited, thanks bro :)